# "Adaptive band" type software to accompany solo practice and jam sessions

Tags: guitar, practice, software

<sub>I'm not 100% if this is the right place to post the question. It's connected primarily with music, so I feel like it's OK, but... well... In case it isn't, please direct me to a better suited location and I'll delete this question.</sub>

I really like the ["adaptive band"](http://www.trueachievements.com/n15023/form-an-instant-adaptive-band-in-rocksmith-2014.htm) in Rocksmith 2014. For those who don't know what this is, it's mode in a video game where you can pick and choose accompanying instruments, tempo and tone and the "adaptive band" will play along with you, as you play on your guitar. This is awesome. You can enforce a steady tempo, or it the "band" can change it on the fly to match what I'm playing. Same thing goes for volume or tone. Generally, it's a really fun way to get some creativity flowing.

That said, I feel because it's part of a video game it limits what I can do with it. Getting it working is a hassle if I just want to do some bluesy improv with a light band in the background when the notion strikes me. Recording anything is also complicated. Finally, Rocksmith uses it's own proprietary USB connection, which I feel degrades the quality when I have dedicated hardware (of much better quality) connecting my guitar to my PC.

I was wondering if there are any alternatives to Rocksmiths "adaptive band". Unfortunately, looking for "adaptive band alternative" in Google yields results which are very remote from what I'm actually looking for.

Can someone tell me if such software exists and if it does, what should I be looking for?

Comment: Check out the Trio Band Creator by Digitech (http://digitech.com/en-US/products/trio) It is somewhat adaptive but you have to train it for the current song.  It won't change tempo on the fly - maintains what you start out with.  But in real life, you don't usually change tempo on  the fly.  So this will help you maintain a steady tempo which is what you want to do.

Comment: I like my trio too. I take that on trips because it is compact and turnkey. That with the sequencer pedal is challenging and fun. Can spend hours on it combined with iRig and iPad.

Answer (score 2):

check out iReal Pro. It can play back chord progressions from thousands of songs and you can choose a style or tempo for the play back. Great for practicing soloing.

Comment: Yeah! iReal Pro is awesome too! I use that when I meet with other musicians. It's a great way to jam alone or collaborate as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Rocksmith the "adaptive band" functionality isn't really adaptive. All they have implemented is a large number of parallel recordings with slightly different styles, and dependent on your skills in the game it decides which one will get played at any time.

So there isn't actually any adaptation happening as regards your playing. The game is just moving tracks.

There isn't anything else in this space because the only way to make it work is to record those multiple versions and allow the choice of which is being played at any time to be varied based on scoring effectiveness - and that's only going to ever happen in a game.

What you are describing you want - is best delivered by jamming with other people. It's cheap, it's 100% adaptive, and it's far more fun than any game can be.

Oh, and you can end up making money from it :-)

Comment: As much as I like the answer, I can't really +1 it, as it doesn't answer my problem (i.e. looking for software I could use whenever the notion strikes me). Heck, even if the software isn't really adaptive and "cheats" but still works by doing so, it's OK. Finally, it may be a bit sad, but given that I'm but an amateur guitarists I don't have other people to jam with, so there's that too. :S

Comment: 99% of all guitarists are amateurs. Of course you can find like minded folks to have a jam with

Comment: If pressed, I'm sure I'd find it true. But really, I'm having enough trouble as it is coordinating a P&P RPG with my friends; getting strangers to jam with likely isn't any easier and is out of the question when it comes to some spontaneous guitar-playing.

Comment: Alternatives? Do like I did when I was 12/13 and play along to the radio. In fact, I still do it occasionally, 60 odd yrs on! That REALLY keeps you on your toes, and gives a huge variety of styles, keys, etc. And, because they're real songs, it put me in a great position when I did, as the good Dr suggests, start to play with other real players.

Answer (score 1):

Band In A Box!!! That is what I use for exactly that. It is also what I use to put lyrics to music. It is great for improv practice or actual composition of concepts. I usually take the BIAB track and import that into studio one, then play guitar and/or vocals over that.